# is it possible to add LDAP users into local etc/passwd?

Tags: linux, ldap, redhat, openldap, rhel8

I am trying to deploy on demand user into the LDAP user. if it is posible add ldap user on /etc/passwd we can provide access for on demand users.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use [SSSD](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/system-level_authentication_guide/sssd) with Red Hat when using LDAP.
Which does not put the user in "/etc/passwd" but uses trick to allow the user to Authenticate for those "on demand users".

Comment: Do you know any such trick or method?

Comment: Configure SSSD which is included in Red Hat.